# Comparing two Excel Tables and returning boolean value

Tags: excel, comparison, substring

I am a new in using more complex functions to compare two tables, I have problems in solving the following issue:

In Table1 I have like 10 columns, where one column (say E) contains a very long String, where substring is an email address.

E.g.: lslökglöksdögkögöksdögk---test@testmail.com--jsdklfjgjkdsöfgjsdkfjgkjsdg

In Table2 I have 3 columns and one column is full of e-mail addresses only (say column C).

Now I want to get an 11th column in Table1, giving me a boolean return value, wherever the email-adress in C, Table2, is a substring of the column E in Table1. As I said, I am new in Excel, as things like VLookUp don't seem to work (is this even correct to use?). I am nearly trying to achieve this via java-programming...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your Table1 is in "Sheet1" and Table2 is in "Sheet2".

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!E1,Sheet2!C:C, 0)), FALSE, TRUE)
```

Comment: I think I understand, what you want to do, but in this example it should work, but gives me FALSE as return value

Comment: Oops! I think I misunderstood your question. Does column "E" in sheet1 will always have string in the same format like: `"some text"---"emailid"--"sometext"` ?

Comment: Well, there is no pattern in the E-Column of sheet1. So I basically want to find this substring-email in E which should be in Sheet2, Column C.

Comment: I am afraid to say that if there is no pattern in column "E" then it will be very difficult to extract the email from column.